# Indexing considerations in Couchbase.

Tags: couchbase

I want to know analysis of MapReduce view indexer against GSI indexer in couchbase. I mean which indexing to use and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/october/determine-data-access-in-couchbase) and see if this does not clear it up for you. It should. If not, please do come back and refine your questions.